# directive that adds other directives to the same element in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

How do I create a directive that adds other directives to an element?

For example, I want:

```
<input tag/>
```

to be linked as:

```
<input ng-pattern='/[\\w\\d]+/' ng-maxlength='10'/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `$compile()`, a link function, or `terminal` are necessary.  Angular will automatically compile the `telement` for us.

```
.directive('tag', [function() {
  return {
    priority: 1000,
    compile: function(telement, attrs) {
      attrs.$set('tag', null);
      attrs.$set('ngMaxlength', '10');
      attrs.$set('ngPattern', '/[\\w\\d]+/');
    }
  };
}]);
```

Tested with this HTML:

```
<input ng-model="test" ng-init="test=2" tag>
{{test}}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xNuDowy9lgkGB7ySAEF0?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out attrs.$set to me! However, it doesn't seem that using this to set ng-model works. Any ideas why not? A modification of your plunker showing this: http://plnkr.co/edit/ad2zIbNqW800KZi2Ulxn?p=preview

Comment: @MrException, I don't know why it doesn't work.  Here's a SO question about this very issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405790/adding-ngmodel-to-input-with-a-directive

Comment: Super @Mark, I had been pulling out my hair trying `attrs.$set('ng-pattern')` and not understanding why it looked identical in html but nothing was happening.  I wanted to note that—in my quick tests with current Firefox and Chrome and Angular 1.0.7 at least—the `priority: 1000` doesn't seem to be needed for the pattern ng-validation to work.

Comment: This does not work for new versions of angular (1.3+)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that seems to work:

```js
.directive('tag', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    priority: 1000,
    terminal: true,
    compile: function(telement, attrs) {
      attrs.$set('tag', null);
      attrs.$set('ngMaxlength', '10');
      attrs.$set('ngPattern', '/[\\w\\d]+/');

      var link = $compile(telement);

      return function($scope, $element) {
        link($scope, function(clonedElement) {
         $element.replaceWith(clonedElement);
        });
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

The key is making sure that the directive has a higher priority than all the other directives on the element and terminating, so that other directives arent compiled and linked.