# Adding ngModel to input with a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an input element and I would like to bind a ngModel and a ngClass to it using a custom directive, but I'm having some troubles.

What I have:

```
<input type="text" myDirective="PropertyFromScope" />
```

What I want as result:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="PropertyFromScope" ng-class="{'class' : MethodFromScope}" />
```

I'm trying to avoid using templates, because I want the directive to work with any input tag.

Here's what I got so far:

```
angular.module('customDirectives', [])
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$set('ngModel', attrs.myDirective);
        attrs.$set('ngClass', '{\'class\' : MethodFromScope}');
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'A',        
        link: linker
    }
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8QJJ/

Comment: kindly share your directive code

Comment: Added, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 12):

Are you trying to accomplish this ?

Pretty simple solution:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',        
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            element.attr('ng-model', attrs.myDirective);
            element.removeAttr("my-directive");
            element.attr('ng-class', '{\'class\' : testFunction()}');
            return {
               pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { },
               post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { 
                 $compile(iElement)(scope);
               }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/V9e9M/

Comment: Yes! I see that the generated html is correct, but the bindings don't seem to work.

Comment: @AndréLourenço are you doing anything more in your directive ?

Comment: Just added a jsfiddle that shows that the binding is not working.

Comment: Just for clarity of other readers, I can confirm @André's findings match my own directive where I was trying to set ng-pattern. When I `$set('ng-pattern')`, the html _looked_ right but nothing was happening; but it worked when I `$set('ngPattern')` instead (thanks to [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15558038/135114))

Comment: @Daryn so long ago... trying to catch back up on this thread.

Comment: How can you do this and use the ngModelController?

Im getting an error when i add

require:'ngModel'

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to get this to work in a compile function (it added the attributes, but it did not seem to notice them).  However, this linking function seems to work:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var wrappedElement = angular.element(
                '<input type="' + attrs.type + '" ng-model="' 
                 + attrs.myDirective + '">');
            element.replaceWith(wrappedElement);
            $compile(wrappedElement)(scope);
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pCPdK/)

Note: I forgot to add ng-class, but I assume if ng-model works, ng-class should work.

**Update**:

Here's a version that uses a compile function:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            // for some unknown-to-me reason, the input must
            // be wrapped in a span or div:
            var tplElement = angular.element('<span><input></span>');
            var inputEl = tplElement.find('input');
            inputEl.attr('type', tAttrs.type);
            inputEl.attr('ng-model', tAttrs.myDirective);
            tElement.replaceWith(tplElement);
        }
    };
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqQRL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I landed on this page with a similar problem, binding an ngModel with a custom directive.  The question is a few years old, but maybe my solution will help someone else.

First, in the index.html, I'm using my custom directive with some made-up attributes.  Note the dash-case in the html.  The attribute values are what I want to use in the directive.

```
index.html

<div>
    <form name="userInfo">
        <my-custom-directive for-model="ctrl.userInput"
                             for-label="Enter User Info"
                             for-other="more info for the directive">
        <my-custom-directive>
    </form>
</div>
// check to see the binding.
{{ ctrl.userInput }}
```

Next, in the partial.html, I'm going to set some default values to see when the directive is working properly, and when I see the defaults.

```
partial.html

<div class="form-group">
    <label>blankLabel</label>
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           ng-model="modelBlank">
</div>
```

The directive needs some different syntax, which is probably the most common problem.  I like to define a variable, as I'm likely assigning multiple attributes.  Then call .attr() on the variable and pass the new info you want to apply.  In this case, literally 'ng-model' and the value of the custom attribute set in index.html.

```
directive.js

.directive('myCustomDirective', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'partial.html',
        compile: function (element, attributes) {
            // Find the right element in the partial and assign a variable
            var inputTag = element.find('input');
            // use .attr() on the variable and pass it two arguments.
            inputTag.attr('ng-model', attributes.forModel);
            // Find a different element in the partial and replace the text.
            var labelTag = element.find('label');
            labelTag.html(attributes.forLabel);
        }
    };
})
```

You can use console.log(element), but it's going to generate a lot of info.  Better to inspect the element once the page loads to see the ng-model set to the custom value.  If it's hooked up correctly, the {{ ctrl.userInput }} on the index.html page should show the text typed into the form.

This is a lot of work, but now myCustomDirective can be reused with different info passed in:

```
<my-custom-directive for-model="ctrl.userName"
                     for-label="Enter Your Name:"
                     for-other="more info for the directive">
<my-custom-directive>
<my-custom-directive for-model="ctrl.userSelection"
                     for-label="Make a selection:"
                     for-other="more info for the directive">
<my-custom-directive>
```

Personally, I've never had a problem adding attributes or angular directives with this method, including stuff like uib-typeahead.  Just remember to observe the syntax differences between the html and the javascript.