# How would I go about adding directives to an existing directive programmatically whilst ensuring that they have access to the same model?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have attempted the following which seems to generate the correct html, but doesn't perform the data binding i.e. the new directives that I add do not have access to the $modelValue in ngController:

```
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.aModel = {"key": "value"}
    function init() {
       $scope.aModel = {"key": "value"}
    }
}])

.directive('innerDirective', [function (){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '<ul></ul>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModelController) {
            console.log(ngModelController.$modelValue) // Doesnt work
        }
    }
}])

.directive('outerDirective', ["$log", "$compile", function($log, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {},
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelController) {
            ngModelController.$render = function() {
                var aModel = ngModelController.$modelValue; // Works
                 var modelName = attrs['ngModel']; // aModel
                var html = '<inner-directive ng-model="' + modelName + '"></inner-directive>';
                var angularElement = angular.element(html);
                elem.append(angularElement);
                $compile(angularElement)(scope);
            }
        }
    };
}])
```

HTML looks like:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
        <outer-directive ng-model="aModel"></outer-directive>
</div>
```

This is based on reccomendations from another question: [Adding ngModel to input with a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405790/adding-ngmodel-to-input-with-a-directive)

What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Cheers.

Comment: It seems that you have typo.  elem.append(compiledHtml); where compiledHtml is defined in your directive?

Comment: Yep, fixed - I abstracted this from more complex code so as to make it for readable so forgive the mistakes. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two issue:

1- `outerDirective` is using isolated scope. so `aModel` value is `undefinded` in the directive scope.

2-You can't access `ngModelController.$modelValue` in link function immediately. Look at `outerDirective` that you access it in the `render` function.

So you can change your directives as follows:

```
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.aModel = { "key": "value" }
            function init() {
                $scope.aModel = { "key": "value" }
            }
        }]);

        app.directive('innerDirective', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            require: 'ngModel',
            template: '<ul></ul>',
            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModelController) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    console.log(ngModelController.$modelValue) // It works
                });
            }
        }
    }]);

    app.directive('outerDirective', ["$log", "$compile", function ($log, $compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            require: 'ngModel',

            template: '<div></div>',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelController) {
                ngModelController.$render = function () {
                    var aModel = ngModelController.$modelValue; // Works
                    var modelName = attrs['ngModel']; // aModel
                    var html = '<inner-directive ng-model="' + modelName + '"></inner-directive>';
                    var angularElement = angular.element(html);
                    elem.append(angularElement);
                    $compile(angularElement)(scope);
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: This did the trick - it was the isolated scope causing the issue! My understanding of that is still minimal so will do some reading. Much appreciated.